# Need to use table alias inside @Formula annotation in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Is there a way to reference the current table's alias inside of a @Formula annotation in Hibernate?  I want to use the RRN() function which takes in the table name or alias if the table is aliased as a parameter.  I tried specifying the table name directly in the annotation but that won't work because the table is aliased.

I also tried {alias} hoping it may be available but it didn't work either.

```
@Formula("RRN({alias})")
```

I'm looking to generate a query like this:

```
select alias.column1, alias.column2, alias.column3, RRN(alias) from table as alias
```

Comment: Such a simple question it seems. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I didn't find a solution and I gave up looking :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it was fixed in [Resolve {alias} in @Formula like Restrictions.sqlRestriction()](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12280)